# Laravel Eloquent Relationships - Integrity constraint violation

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I have 3 models: Priority, Task and User

**Priority**

- can be assigned to many tasks
- belongs to one user

Code ...

```
class Priority extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'hexcolorcode'];

    protected $casts = [
        'user_id' => 'int',
    ];

    public function task()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

**Task**

- has one priority assigned
- belongs to one user

Code ...

```
class Task extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    protected $casts = [
        'user_id' => 'int',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function priority()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Priority::class);
    }
}
```

**User**

- can have many tasks
- can have many priorities

Code ...

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
    }

    public function priorities()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Priority::class);
    }
}
```

**TaskController**

```
class TaskController extends Controller
{
    protected $tasks;

    private $priorities;

    public function __construct(TaskRepository $tasks, PriorityRepository $priorities)
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->tasks = $tasks;
        $this->priorities = $priorities;
    }

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        return view('tasks.index', [
            'tasks' => $this->tasks->forUser($request->user()),
            'priorities' => $this->priorities->forUser($request->user())
        ]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'description' => 'required',
            'priority' => 'required'
        ]);

        $request->user()->tasks()->create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'priority_id' => $request->priority
        ]);

        return redirect('/tasks');
    }

    public function edit(Task $task)
    {
        $this->authorize('edit', $task);

        return view('tasks.edit', compact('task'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Task $task)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
        ]);

        $task->update($request->all());
        return redirect('/tasks');
    }

    public function destroy(Request $request, Task $task)
    {
        $this->authorize('destroy', $task);

        $task->delete();

        return redirect('/tasks');
    }
}
```

**Error**

Now when I want to store a task it gives me following error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tasks`.`tasks`,
>   CONSTRAINT `tasks_priority_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`priority_id`)
>   REFERENCES `priorities` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `tasks` (`name`,
>   `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (test task, 1,
>   2016-05-01 14:11:21, 2016-05-01 14:11:21))

Is it possible with this construct or do I have to use Polymorphic Relations between priority table and tasks table?

**My Tables**

Database Model Picture: http://picpaste.de/mysql-kBH4tO5T.PNG

```
class CreatePrioritiesTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('priorities', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->char('name');
            $table->char('hexcolorcode', 7);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }
}


class CreateTasksTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->integer('priority_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('priority_id')->references('id')->on('priorities');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

**PriorityController**

```
class PriorityController extends Controller
{

    protected $priorities;

    public function __construct(PriorityRepository $priorities)
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->priorities = $priorities;
    }

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        return view('priority.index', [
            'priorities' => $this->priorities->forUser($request->user()),
        ]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'hexcolorcode' => 'required|max:7'
        ]);

        $request->user()->priorities()->create($request->all());

        return redirect('/priorities');
    }

    public function edit(Priority $priority)
    {
        $this->authorize('edit', $priority);

        return view('priority.edit', compact('priority'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Priority $priority)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'hexcolorcode' => 'required|max:7'
        ]);

        $priority->update($request->all());
        return redirect('/priorities');
    }

    public function destroy(Request $request, Priority $priority)
    {
        $this->authorize('destroy', $priority);

        $priority->delete();

        return redirect('/priorities');
    }
}
```

Comment: Also i checked your db schema. Why do you need userid in priority table? A user must have a priority for a given task if i am right isnt? You can remove userid from priority table too. So you have it this way. A user have many tasks and each task have a priority. This way even if you need to find out what tasks user have or what priority he has set for a given task. You can query it easily. If i have understood your problem well

Comment: Or is it that each user first creates priority and then sets it to the task? Because without creating priority u r storing so you endup with foreign key error. How do you want to solve this.

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia yes a user first create a priority and than creates a task with a priority assigned to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I added the priority_id attribute to the fillable array inside the task model.

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'description', 'priority_id'];
```

I had an understanding problem, because user_id is assigned automatically from the framework, but it isn't specified in fillable array. That's because I say $request->user->tasks->create(); it is assigned from the framework, but priority_id is assigned through the user, so it is mass assigned and need to be specified in the fillable array.

@Murlidhar Fichadia

Answer (score 0):

In your store method. The create method it says :

user->tasks(). This bit will only inserting data in user and tasks table. Thats why you have foreign key error. As you are not updating one of your tables(priority) and also you have added foreign keys in tables as i csn see from migration.

What you are trying to achieve is right if you had a pivot table called task_user where you had userid, taskid and a priority_id. That would be perfect as you would simply update the priority column with userid and taskid. Thats one way but it will require few changes OR you can insert data into user and tasks table seperately for which you will need to just change the query. What do you prefer? I can show you an example for which you like.

```
    //for Priority
        // store
        $priorities = new Priority;
        $priorities->name       = Input::get('priority_name');
        $priorities->hexcolorcode      = Input::get('hexcolorcode');
        $priorities->save();

        $priority = Priority::select('id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();

    //for Task
    $tasks = new Task;
        $tasks->name       = Input::get('task_name');
        $tasks->priority_id      = Input::get('priority');
        $priorities->save();

        // redirect
        return Redirect::to('some view please change this');
```

Please explain views or show screenshots, how are you handling it. For now, I have given you the solution with one controller handling priorities and tasks.

Comment: I would be okey to store first the task and then update its priority. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Okay I will get you the desired solution.

Comment: I dont know really how do you have views. Do user have two different forms in two different views to create priority and then add tasks with assigned priority? how are you handling the views at the moment.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion! yes the user has two different controller and two different views to add priorities and tasks. I updated my post with the whole taskController and priorityController

Comment: I seem to find your controllers fine.  Is your problem resolved now?

Comment: no still the same problem, I changed nothing still same controller as from the time I wrote this post

Comment: I think its because here: $request->user()->tasks()->create([]),  the framework cannot link to the priority table and from there I have the linking to my priority_id in my tasks table, or am I wrong?

Comment: Can you try without eloquent model and how I did above in my solution. for now pls comment $request->users()->tasks thing.. and see if you can get it to work how I am doing. Also are you passing priority id as input from form ? because you mentioned $request->priority_id

Comment: Yes what you are doing currently in the controller. trying tp update the priority table using users->prioritites() is wrong. because you have has many relation. its normally when you have Many to Many relationship or other. You cant do with one to one or one to many relationship.